# Protractor throws "Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page" when a button is clicked

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

I am writing E2E tests for my angular web application using protractor and jasmine. My scenario is that after clicking an "update" button my website reloads, after reloading it lands on the same page which is angular, if the site takes too long to reload protractor will throw the following error:

> Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined. This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping. See https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2643 for details"

I have applied all the solution here on stack overflow but none of them solve the problem. I have tried following enabling and disabling synchronization:

1. Browser.ignoresync = true;
2. click update button
3. browser.sleep(3000);
4. Browser.ignoresync = false;

I have also tried simple browser sleep but none of them worked. This problem is variable some times it throws error and some times it doesn't. My guess is that it throws error when the site takes longer then the sleep time to load.

I am using following versions of protractor and jasmine:

```
"protractor": "5.4.2",
"jasmine": "2.8.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

`browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` is deprecated try `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);` after clicking the `update` button in your application.

So this maeks your protractor to wait until all the angular modules are completely loaded.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicion about the timeout occurring when the site takes longer to load seems correct to me as you are seeing the issue with your first page interaction. I would add a `browser.wait` instead of that explicit wait to allow your page the time it needs.

```
browser.wait(
   element(by.buttonText('Update')), 
   10*1000, 
   'Page did not load within 10 seconds (update btn not present)'
)
```